# I want to enable VT-x (virtualization) and I can't find it in my BIOS

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, bios, virtualization

My processor is an AMD A6-6310 APU.

I can't find any option for virtualization in the BIOS (version A2CN24WW(V1.06) )

I checked this particular processor's features, and found out that virtualization is supported in this processor.

Is there any way I can enable virtualization?

Comment: AMD CPUs don't have VT-x that is an Intel feature.

Answer (score 6):

The basic virtualization support in AMD processors is named SVM. VT-x is intel-only name.

Look for "SVM Mode" in BIOS under CPU configuration.

Comment: And if you can't find an option for it in your BIOS, then consider A) Maybe it's always enabled, and B) A BIOS update may add an option to enable/disable it.